# Host a COM server inside my process

Tags: com, com+, dcom

I know I can register my COM object to be consumed `inproc` (via standard com registration) and `outproc` (via dcom) hosted in a dedicated dllhost.exe process.

But is it possible to have my COM object run in an `external process` to the consumer (like dcom) only not hosted in dllhost rather my own process?

My goal is to have a process (windows service) running my logic, and just host a COM object so that other processes can communicate with me using simple `CoCreateInstance` of the COM object. Is it possible?

Please don't offer other protocols as an answer, if it's not possible to host COM that way is a sufficient enough answer.

Thanks!

Comment: COM has the notion of DLL Surrogates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695225.aspx. dllhost.exe is the default surrogate process, you can write a custom one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682432.aspx. However when you say "host a COM object so that other processes can communicate with me using simple CoCreateInstance of the COM object", you don't need all that (complex) plumbing. Just host and register the COM object from your Windows Service. It's called an Out-Of-Process COM server.

Comment: When you create a new Visual Studio project using the `ATL project` template, the wizard will ask you to choose whether you want to host it in dll, exe or service exe. That's probably the easiest way to start. See the second paragraph here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier - if you'll move your comment to a reply I'll tag is the answer. thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM has the notion of [DLL Surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695225.aspx):

> COM makes it possible to create DLL servers that can be loaded into a
>   surrogate EXE process. This combines the ease of writing DLL servers
>   with the benefits of executable implementation. Development tools like
>   Microsoft Visual Studio facilitate the writing of DLL servers, but a
>   DLL server in itself has limits

`dllhost.exe` that we often see running (as one or multiple instances) in the background is in fact the default surrogate process, but you can write a custom one: [Writing a Custom Surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682432.aspx). This is something that is rarely seen.

However when you say "host a COM object so that other processes can communicate with me using simple CoCreateInstance of the COM object", I don't think you need all that plumbing (that can be rather complex to implement). Just host and register the COM object from your Windows Service. It's called an [Out-Of-Process COM server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835.aspx) as opposed to In-Process COM server (a DLL).